# How to change mode for a file on CentOS 7?

Tags: centos, chmod

Want to change a file's mode to `-rw-------`.

Use `chmod 755 ~/.ssh/authorized_keys` got a result as:

```
$ ls -la ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 755 Dec 11 03:09 /root/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

But want to get this this result:

```
-rw-------. 1 root root 755 Dec 11 03:09 /root/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

Not work. It can been changed if use `chmod 600`. However, it shows as `755`.

Comment: Are you getting any error messages when you run `chmod 600 /root/.ssh/authorized_keys`?

Comment: @ajgringo619 No, nothing.

Comment: I think you're getting confused by the 755 you see between "root" and "Dec". That's simply the **size** of the file: it's 755 bytes long. Just do `chmod 600`, that's all you need here. It should show as `-rw-------` correctly as expected.

Comment: @filbranden Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do the maths in your head and convert permission bits to octal, but it's much much easier to use the symbolic permissions. In this instance you need to know that the first group is for the owner (u=user), the second is for the group (g), and the third is for everyone else (o=other)

```
chmod u=rw,go= ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

Instead of `755` you would use `u=rwx,go=rx`, and instead of `764` you would use `u=rwx,g=rw,o=r`. Of course, `755` is quicker than the symbolic equivalent, but not naturally as easy to see what it means.